# Google Spreadsheets: formula to set the shortest string value for each rows with the same key-value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need a formula to set the shortest string value for each rows with the same key-value.
Please take a look a the capture to see what I mean.
Here the editable file with the example of the capture: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dISlj6fmnOTIvlEOHNcyAOAgRa1GM-u17_YO-2n2UTw/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(F2:F;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;+sort((filter({B:B\len(B:B)};A:A=Σ));2;1))))
```

- also it is assumed here that expected output in `Cell G3` is `abc` & not `abd`. let us know if its indeed `abd` and there's some logic to that...

[image]

Comment: I was puzzling in the same direction but came up with `=MAP(TOCOL(F2:F;1);lambda(Σ;VLOOKUP(Σ;SORT({A:B\len(B:B)};3;1);2;0)))`. Not sure if there would be any benefit.

Comment: @JvdV yeah the lookup perspective should workout perfect as is:)